# run a function which the timestamp stored in database is of previous week

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a plugin in which I need to detect that the timestamp stored in the database is of the previous week . The current logic I have is that I get the timestamp stored from database and compare it with current date and if its 7 days old I perform the action , but I always wanted to detect if the timestamp is from the previous week so that 7 days logic of mine is not correct as if the timestamp was created on previous Saturday and is of previous week ,my 7 days check logic will fail there . The code i wrote is

```
$date=$active_row->timestamp;
$timestamp_start = $date;
$timestamp_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$difference = abs($timestamp_end - $timestamp_start); // that's it!
$days = floor($difference/(60*60*24));

if ($days >7){
    run ()
}
```

How can I detect that the timestamp is of previous week ?

Comment: I propose to build a query that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the week number from both the dates, compare them and deduce accordingly..

```
$ddate = "2012-10-18";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W"); // This is your week number
```

Comment: or you can use `date('N', $timestamp)`

Comment: it echos 32 as week number

Comment: subtract the week number of your timestamp from this value and check whether the difference is greater than zero. I would do this in SQL, btw: `SELECT WEEK(NOW()) - WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) > 0 as test ...`

Comment: 1. Get the current timestamp, calculates it's week number. 2. Get the week number from the respective timestamp. compare both of them, if first is greater than second, that means the respective timestamp if from previous week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  $day    =  86400;
  $myTime =  $active_row->timestamp ;// or to test use time()-($day*7);


  if (  $myTime <= ( time()-($day*7)  )   )
  {
      echo " one Week or older ";
  }
```

Comment: provide me with `$active_row->timestamp` output plz

Comment: 1407507106 is the output

Answer (score 0):

You can find last Monday with   `$week1 =strtotime("last Monday");`

Then

```
$week2 = str_to_time("+1 week",$week1).

$week1 = date("Y/m/d",$week1);
$week2 = daet("Y/m/d",$week2);
```

if your date is in between these two dates,  your condition is true.